# Detect which picture box is being right clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

in my application you right click a picture box and it brings a toolstrip item to change that picture box image when you click an option, my question is how to know which picture box is being clicked in order to just change the image of the picture box that is being right clicked instead of creating 1 toolstrip item for each picturebox?

Update, found the solution.

```
private void redToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = ((ContextMenuStrip)(((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Owner)).
              SourceControl;
    if (box == PictureBox1)
    {
        PictureBox1.Image = Form1.Properties.Resources.red_square_button;
    }
    else if (box == PictureBox2)
    {
        PictureBox2color = "red";
        PictureBox2.Image = Form1.Properties.Resources.red_square_button;
    }
}
```

Explanation: When you click a toolstrip menu item, the code will only affect the picture box that is being right clicked.

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe same event handler to `MouseClick` event of all pictureboxes. Then cast sender of event to `PictureBox` to get instance of picturebox which raised event:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        return;

    PictureBox picutreBox = (PictureBox)sender; 
    // use picutreBox
}
```

Comment: Then what do I do when the toolstrip item is clicked?

Comment: @JoseCardama you want to *'Detect which picture box is being right clicked'*. If you want to use it later, then you can save it in `CurrentPictureBox` field

Comment: What I want is when a toolstrip item is clicked change the image of the picture box that is being right clicked.

Comment: @JoseCardama then use approach which I just suggested

Comment: Something like this?

        private void defaultToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (picutreBox == PictureBox1)
            {
            PictureBox1.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
            }
            else if (picutreBox == PictureBox2)
            {
                PictureBox2.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
            }
        }

Comment: @JoseCardama simply assign image to current box `private void defaultToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { pictureBox.Image =  Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.black_square_button; }`

Comment: The problem If I do that is that I would have to create 1 toolstrip menu for every picture box, then what I was wondering is if I could do that with just 1 toolstrop.